# Hiding Input and Label via CSS

Tags: css

I'm using the mailchimp plugin for wordpress and need to hide some of the segments on a list. How would I direct css to hide these elements specific to their name?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group[841][1]" id="mc_interest_841_Camp C" class="mc_interest" value="Camp C">
<label for="mc_interest_841_Camp C" class="mc_interest_label">Camp C</label>
```

Comment: you could use `visibility:hidden` or maybe `display:none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the class name is static then you can do something like this:

```
.mc_interest input {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: while the class is static for the label, mc_interest_label, I'm trying to accomplish hiding all but one. Using:

.mc_interest input, .mc_interest label { visibility:hidden; display:none; }

I was able to hide the elements, but their space is still displayed.

Comment: strange it shouldn't if you used `display:none`

Comment: I had my answer updated, you can also add width: 0; if necessary.

Comment: @EdwinBautista that's seems more like an hack. Proper usage would be to use display:none

Comment: hmmmm, i think since he use both properties, visibility is overriding the display property. Remove visibility: hidden then. ^_^